# $\frac{G}{H}$ and $\frac{G}{N}$ nilpotent $H \cap N = 1$ $\rightarrow$ $G$ is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Prove that if $N,H \triangleleft G$ and $\frac{G}{H}$ and $\frac{G}{N}$ are nilpotent and $H \cap N = 1$ then $G$ is nilpotent.

$proof:$ By the second isomorphism theorem we have:

$\frac{HK}{K} \cong \frac{H}{H\cap N} \cong H$

Since $\frac{HK}{K} \leq \frac{G}{K}$ and $\frac{G}{K}$ is nilpotent, we have that $\frac{HK}{K}$ is nilpotent. Thus $H$ is nilpotent.

A similar arguement shows that $K$ is nilpotent.

I do not know how to proceed from here... if only nilpotentcy was a characteristic that was closed under extensions!!

Comment: $g  \mapsto (gH,gN)$ defines an injective homomorphisms from $G$ to the nilpotent group $G/H \times G/N$.

Comment: Right, I was so close! So $G$ is isomorphic to it's image which is a subgroup of a nilpotent group and so is nilpotent. Thanks!